# Altering/selecting elements in taxonomy XML database

Tags: xml, database, xquery, taxonomy, thesaurus

I have been asked by a co-worker to look into the creation of a database for her taxonomy thesaurus.

So far I have found that simply exporting her taxonomy file to an XML format from her program called "MultiTes" and then importing it in BaseX in order to execute XQueries to be the best solution. However I am open to suggestions if you know of a better way, this is uncharted territory for me, and there does not appear to be a lot of online resources for my task specifically.

**My question is how can I select individual or specific XML elements within the database?** when the structure looks as demonstrated below:

```
<BT level="1">Curricula<BT level="2">Academic<BT level="3">PARTICIPATION BY PROXY</BT>
  </BT>
</BT>
```

The images below give two examples of the XML structure as well as it varies depending on what kind of term it is:

[image]

scrolling a bit further down it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some examples of information from these screenshots that you might want to pull out? And the desired form of the result?

Comment: Likewise it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.